# Posting new Blogs with Tumblr Api v2 in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, oauth, tumblr

I guess Tumblr updated their API so the old ways aren't working.

In regards to the new documentation:
http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting

It's saying I need to use OAuth 1.0a to authenticate to this api (as shown here: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#auth), this is what I have so far and have no idea how else to do what they're asking.

```
RequestURL = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/mytestblog.tumblr.com/post"

RequestStr = "type=text"
RequestStr = RequestStr & "&state=published"
RequestStr = RequestStr & "&title=" & PostTitle
RequestStr = RequestStr & "&body=" & PostBody   


Set objXML=Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    objXML.Open "POST", RequestURL, False
    objXML.Send RequestStr
    Response.Write objXML.ResponseText
Set objXML=Nothing
```

This obviously doesn't work and gives the following response:

```
    {"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}
```

Does anyone have any experience doing this in classic asp?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this API before , but looking at your link what I think you need to do is get an Oauth key and then add it to your object RequestStr - eg using their example

```
RequestStr = RequestStr & "&api_key=PyezS3Q4Smivb24d9SzZGYSuh--IaMfAkE"
```

Comment: How do I get an oAUTH key in classic asp and use it in the request?

Comment: There are instructions on how to get one on the page you link to - http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#auth .  Once you have your key, use it to replace what comes after api_key= in my answer above.